# PyQt - can I add a QWidget in paintEvent?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I am using PyQt to make an application that, amongst other things, shows information in a simple graphical diagram.

I have done this as a QWidget and reimplemented the paintEvent method to do the drawing. A small and very cut-down example is show below.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *    # sloppy, I know, but done for speed! :-)

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Example,self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        base=QWidget()
        layout=QVBoxLayout(base)
        self.diagram=Diagram()
        layout.addWidget(self.diagram)
        self.setCentralWidget(base)

class Diagram(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Diagram,self).__init__(parent)
        self.width=360
        self.height=120
        self.leftMargin=10
        self.topMargin=10

    def paintEvent(self,event=None):
        painter=QPainter(self)
        painter.setWindow(self.leftMargin,self.topMargin,self.width,self.height)
        self.drawConnection(painter, 40, 25, 40, 90)
        self.drawConnection(painter, 40, 90, 40, 110)
        self.drawConnection(painter, 40, 110, 200, 100)
        self.drawItem(painter, 40, 40)
        self.drawItem(painter, 40, 90)
        self.drawState(painter,200,100)

    def drawConnection(self,painter,x0,y0,x1,y1):
        pen=QPen()
        pen.setWidth(4)
        pen.setColor(QColor(50,50,200))
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawLine(x0,y0,x1,y1)

    def drawItem(self,painter,x,y):
        w=40
        h=30
        r=QRectF(x-(w/2),y-(h/2),w,h)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(r,5.0,5.0)
        grad=QLinearGradient(QPointF(15.0,20.0),QPointF(30.0,30.0))
        pen=QPen()
        pen.setWidth(2)
        pen.setColor(QColor(10,10,10))
        painter.setPen(pen)
        brush=QBrush(QColor(0,200,10))
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(r,5.0,5.0)

    def drawState(self,painter,x,y):
        w=80
        h=60
        r=QRectF(x-(w/2),y-(h/2),w,h)
        pen=QPen()
        pen.setWidth(2)
        pen.setColor(QColor(255,10,10))
        painter.setPen(pen)
        brush=QBrush(QColor(200,200,10))
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        painter.drawPie(r,5040,1440)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    example=Example()
    example.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Is it possible to add a QWidget instead of calling drawItem?

For example, a suitably styled QPushButton could go in place of the rounded rectangles.

Alternatively, what is the best way to go about creating a display that contains both widgets and painted items?

Comment: It looks like you are just drawing a colorful Rect but NOT a widget, the rectangle is different with QWidget, as QWidget can handle a lot of event such as click event, keyPressEvent. Why not just add a child widget to the parent widget instead of drawing it yourself? you can use the QSS to set its style, something like rounded rect

Comment: @CuiHeng Maybe I didn't explain it very well. I want to add widgets and then draw my own shapes around them. I've updated the code example - how could I change the rectangles drawn by drawItem for a QPushButton, while still having the other things drawn around them?

Comment: If you want to just display and work through graph display. You might want to try using [https://networkx.github.io]

Answer (score 0):

I have written a rounded child widget example, using the QSS.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys


ROUNDED_STYLE_SHEET = """QPushButton {
     background-color: red;
     border-style: outset;
     border-width: 2px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     border-color: beige;
     font: bold 14px;
     min-width: 10em;
     padding: 6px;
 }
"""


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mChildWidget = QPushButton(self)
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.mChildWidget.resize(120, 80)
        self.mChildWidget.move(300, 200)
        self.mChildWidget.setStyleSheet(ROUNDED_STYLE_SHEET)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: How would I use this widget in place of the green rectangles that I am drawing?